# How to create two application domains, each of them with its own separate window (as opposed to get embedded in host window)?

Tags: c#

I am learning application domain now.

My host program will call 2 appdomains which call an assembly as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain ad1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("appdom1");
        ad1.ExecuteAssembly("c:\\InputOutput.exe");

        AppDomain ad2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("appdom2");
        ad2.ExecuteAssembly("c:\\InputOutput.exe");

        Console.Write("Press any key to unload");

        Console.ReadLine();

        AppDomain.Unload(ad1);
        AppDomain.Unload(ad2);
    }
}
```

How to make each appdom  have its own separate window rather than reside in the  host application?

Thank  you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create threads to make that work.  Calling Thread.SetApartmentState() is required to make them STA threads.  Not so sure this will come to a good end, neither Windows Forms nor WPF has any support for arbitrating windows in separate app domains.  Maybe it will work.